# Schedule a one-time Resque job on heroku on application start in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, resque, resque-scheduler

I am using Resque and Resque Schedule to start a job that has to be run immediately on the application start. Other scheduled jobs are loaded every 30 seconds.

This is the code for my config/initializers/redis.rb

```
require 'rake'
require 'resque'
require 'resque/server'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'
# This will make the tabs show up.
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'

uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
Resque.redis = REDIS
Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/workers/*.rb"].each { |file| require file }
Resque.enqueue(AllMessageRetriever)
Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'schedule.yml'))
```

When the application is started up, the AllMessageRetriever gets run 2-3 times rather than only once. Do the initializers get called more than once? This happens both on Heroku and my local environment?

Is it possible to set a delayed job in Resque-Scheduler which will only get executed once and immediately on runtime?

The code for AllMessageRetriever. Basically it loops over a table and calls an external API to get data and then updates it to the table. This entire task happens 2-3 times if I add the enqueue method in initializer file

```
 require 'socialcast'
module AllMessageRetriever
    @queue = :message_queue
    def self.perform()
        Watchedgroup.all.each do |group|    
            puts "Running group #{group.name}"
            continueLoading=true
            page=1
            per_page=500
            while(continueLoading == true)
                User.first.refresh_token_if_expired
                token = User.first.token
                puts "ContinueLoading: #{continueLoading}"
                @test = Socialcast.get_all_messages(group.name,token,page,per_page)

                messagesArray =  ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@test)["messages"]
                puts "Message Count: #{messagesArray.count}"
                if messagesArray.count == 0
                    puts 'count is zero now'
                    continueLoading = false
                else
                    messagesArray.each do |message|
                        if not Message.exists?(message["id"])   
                            Message.create_with_socialcast(message, group.id)
                        else
                            Message.update_with_socialcast(message)
                        end
                    end
                end
                page += 1
            end
            Resqueaudit.create({:watchedgroup_id => group.id,:timecompleted => DateTime.now})
        end
        # Do anything here, like access models, etc
        puts "Doing my job"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

**Rake**

Firstly, why are you trying to queue on init?

You'd be much better delegating to a [rake task](http://railsguides.net/2012/03/14/how-to-generate-rake-task/) which is called from an initializer.

This will remove dependency on the initialize process, which should clear things up a lot. I wouldn't put this in an initializer itself, as it will be better handled elsewhere ([modularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity))

---

**Problem**

I think this line is causing the issue:

```
Resque.enqueue(AllMessageRetriever)
```

Without seeing the contents of `AllMessageRetriever`, I'd surmise that you're `AllMessageRetriever` (module / class?) will be returning the results 2/3 times, causing Resque to add the (2 / 3 times) data-set to the queue

Could be wrong, but it would make sense, and mean your issue is not with `Resque` / `Initializers`, but your `AllMessageRetriever` class

Would be a big help if you showed it!

Comment: Hi @RichPeck I added the code for the worker class. I have now added it to the Rake task and it works fine. i.e. only once. But the only problem is that I have to manually call the task and it is not done automatically

Comment: This is good news -- perhaps you could create an initializer for the task? Like 

```#config/initializers/messages.rb
Rake::Task["your:task"].invoke```